# What sprite size should I use for 2D game?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I try to create a 2D game for Android. It looks like **Cut the rope** (it isn't a clone but it have same level representation) if it has a value.
My problem that I can't understand that optimal sprite sizes I should use. I.e. what target screen resolution should I use to sprites didn't have anomalies on HD-devices (like Samsung Galaxy S7 and etc., phones and tablets)?

To make my question is clearer I ask about this **1 unit = X pixels** for xxhdpi-screens. What is **X**?

**P.S.** Sorry if it's off-topic I will be grateful for link on the correct community then and if it's a duplicate I will be grateful for link on this post cuz I couldn't find it.

Comment: This question is probably better asked at the game dev stack exchange - https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you! I will ask it there.

Comment: To give some information, for best performance you should always use a multiple of 2 such as commonly seen 16x16, 32x32, 64x64 etc, but it's not a great limitation today and can be disregarded

Comment: @Fredrik, thank you! But I need a resolution more.

Comment: I meant power of 2, not multiple of 2. 2^x will get you a many different resolutions that are optimal for performance. Read more on why here: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/26187/why-are-textures-always-square-powers-of-two-what-if-they-arent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking about the sprites resolution, here is my approach: I create a Photoshop project with the highest targeted screen resolution(mostly 1080p), create every scene then rasterize and export the individual sprites at that same resolution.

Of course if a sprite is used across multiple scenes, I'll export it in highest resolution then scale it down when needed.

Answer (score 1):

I will not explain all researches.
I detected the largest screen form tablets as 2560pxX1600px. Why? From Google's screen size table on the **Android developers** site.
As the next step I divided a game screen by 12. I think in different cases it will be various... But I choose 12 cuz it divides by 4, 3 and 2.
As the final step I devided 1600 by 12 and got about 133px. To improve the result I scaled this number to 128px.
I.e. 128px per unit if the smallest screen side includes 12 units.
**P.S.** Maybe someone will have same problem and it will help him.